# Android studio gradle upgrade

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Anyone has an idea on how to upgrade gradle from within android studio. The pop-up appears telling me to upgrade gradle but version never updates.
I've tried downloading it and unzipping it in the .gralde folder and changing the path, a gradle error persists and resolving it only re-creates the old gradle file and overwrites the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Set gradle and android plugin version under the Projects tab in Project structure (File -> Project Structure). Clicking Ok will sync gradle files.

Alternatively to update gradle through code [this](http://devdeeds.com/update-gradle-plugin-android-studio/) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Update Gradle version**

1. find `gradle` folder inside your project
2. Open `gradle-wrapper.properties`
3. `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip`

**Update Android Gradle plugin**

1. Open `build.gradle` file of your project
2. Inside `buildscript` tag update 
   `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'`

After making these changes refresh gradle dependency.